# Enumerate all algebraic numbers

Tags: algorithm

Could you provide me an algorithm (preferably in C-like language), which is capable of enumerating all [algebraic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_numbers)? Wikipedia states these numbers are countable (unlike real numbers). I have already asked a [similar question on MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364775/bijection-for-algebraic-numbers), but it didn't help me much.

Comment: Isn't this a pure mathematical question? Writing the code after having the algorithm should be a piece of cake, but I would gather you would get more help on a math-related site.

Comment: I hope you know there are infinitely many algebraic numbers...

Comment: Also, this is site for programmers not mathematicians, so it would be nice if you have provided definition for *algebraic numbers* here or at least have linked to Wikipedia entry that defines them. The goal for you when asking question should be to minimize the effort for people that would go about trying to answer your question...

Comment: I went to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) and still don't know what OP wants.

Comment: Your description of what  an algebraic number is, is wrong. Not all algebraic numbers can be expressed using basic arithmetic operations, powers and roots. See [Theorem of Abel and Ruffini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: Thanks. I have removed the description.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to represent algebraic numbers in a way that is fundamentally different than what the definition says: a number at which a polynomial with integer coefficients can be zero. Especially, not all algebraic numbers can be expressed by iteratively applying addition, division, multiplication, subtraction and *n*th root to integers.

Basically the only way to enumerate all algebraic numbers is to enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients. And that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to convert from ordered set of non-negative integers (a1, a2, ..., an) to a single integer B. Integer B, when represented in binary form should look like this:

```
100..00100..00...100..00
 |-a0-| |-a1-|    |-an-|
```

I have a feeling that this could help you, but not sure how, as you haven't properly defined what an algebraic number is, and how it can be constructed, and some such.

Comment: An algebraic number is a number *a* for which a polyonmial *p* with integer coefficients exists, such that *p(a)==0*.